# subprocess.run failing to run command

Tags: python, subprocess

I pass this string to subproccess.run and split on spaces.

This is how I build the string

```
patch_request = f"""/usr/local/bin/kubectl patch secret {secret_name} --type="json" -p='[{{"op":"replace","path":"/data/{k}","value":"{v}"}}]'"""
```

It produces

```
/usr/local/bin/kubectl patch secret beta --type="json" -p=\'[{"op":"replace","path":"/data/foo","value":"mock_value"}]\'
```

I end up getting this error back. Any idea what could be going wrong?

```
CompletedProcess(args=['/usr/local/bin/kubectl', 'patch', 'secret', 'beta', '--type="json"', '-p=\'[{"op":"replace","path":"/data/foo","value":"mock_value"}]\''], returncode=1, stdout='', stderr='error: --type must be one of [json merge strategic], not "\\"json\\""\n')
```

Comment: maybe try replace "json" -> json

Comment: @kosciej16 then that results in ```CompletedProcess(args=['/usr/local/bin/kubectl', 'patch', 'secret', 'beta', '--type=json', '-p=\'[{"op":"replace","path":"/data/foo","value":"mock_value"}]\''], returncode=1, stdout='', stderr='Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type jsonpatch.Patch\n')```

Comment: I think the quoted single quotes are getting in your way.  It's not `--type=json'` that is causing the error.  This is invalid JSON: `\'[{"op":"replace","path":"/data/foo","value":"mock_value"}]\'`

Comment: Also:  Recommend you construct the exec arg by arg instead of doing split.  Among other things, it will reduce the quoting headaches mixing args with JSON which uses double quotes extensively.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti they need to be single quotes though. Any easy way around it? As far as I'm aware those \ don't actually exist in the string, just in the REPL.

Comment: What needs to be single quotes?  The value attached to `-p=` is supposed to be  plain valid JSON, yes?    No single quotes in JSON.  Typically you need single quotes in the *shell* to protect all the double quotes in the JSON.

Comment: You just asked this same question [Remove backslash before single quote from string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674613/remove-backslash-before-single-quote-from-string-literal) an hour ago, people gave you a solution, then you self-deleted it. Please don't do that, it's not allowed. SO has bots which will detect that  Better would be to edit the original question, add your code, and change its title.

Comment: How exactly are you passing this string to `subproccess.run`? It looks to me like you have shell syntax in the string (especially various quotes), but are running it in a way that doesn't pass it through a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building up the command as an array to send to `subprocess.run` instead of doing a string substitution is slightly more work at first but gives much greater flexibility later when args and options need to be conditionally added, changed, etc.  I would set it up this way:

```py
    secret_name = "foo"
    k = 'K1'
    v = 'Dragon\'s "lair"'

    print(v)  # This will come out as  Dragon's "lair"  Note no backslash

    # Set up the baseline command that does not change a lot:                                                         
    cmd = ['/usr/local/bin/kubectl','patch','secret',secret_name,'--type=json']                                      
    
    #  Set up the more variable bits as a regular dict, not JSON. This gives
    #  you great control over setting up the data without worrying about
    #  formatting it into the final JSON representation:                                                     
    parg = {'op':'replace', 'path':'/data/%s' % k}

    # Example of flexibility in complex arg setup -- and note we do not have
    # to worry about the single and double quotes in v:
    parg['value'] = v    

    #  Now, "at the end", turn the more complex args into JSON.  This will, among                                     
    #  other things, take care of args that themselves contain single and double                                      
    #  quotes and other chars that complicate rendering to JSON:                                                      
    cmd.append('-p=%s' % json.dumps(parg))

    #  Run subprocess as a cmd array, not through the shell:                                                          
    p1 = subprocess.run(cmd, text=True, capture_output=True)
    print(p1.stdout)
```

Comment: In the end I need this - 
```patch_request = f'patch secret {self.secret_name} --namespace {self.namespace} --type json -p [{{"op":"replace","path":"/data/{k}","value":"{v}"}}]' ```