# Python subprocess.run() does not run some terminal commands, such as arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I want to call `gcc` for ARM architecture programmatically from Python. Unfortunatelly it seems like some terminal commands cannot be run by the Python subprocess module.

In my terminal, I can run the following command just fine.

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o /path/to/out -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mtune=arm1176jzf-s /path/to/out.s
```

However, when I try to call that command programmatically in Python, using `subprocess.run()`, I get an error.

Code:

```
output_binary = '/path/to/out'
output_assembly = 'path/to/out.s'
subprocess.run(f"arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o {output_binary} " +\
            f"-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mtune=arm1176jzf-s {output_assembly}")
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o /path/to/out -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mtune=arm1176jzf-s /path/to/out.s'
```

But I am sure it is not an `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` problem. Here's what I tried in Python interpreter:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run("cd .. && echo hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 493, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd .. && echo hello'
```

As you can see from above, even the simplest command like `cd` is not consumed by the python.

How to make Python recognise desired commands?

Comment: You either need to use `shell=True` in order to process your command string (but this isn't generally a good idea due to security and efficiency concerns), or provide a list in which the executable and parameters are supplied as separate elements.

Comment: @jasonharper That sounds like an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [subprocess.run failing to run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70675004/subprocess-run-failing-to-run-command)